# Why does Typescript throw an error when I try to create Supabase client file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte, sveltekit, supabase

I am quite new to SvelteKit and Typescript and I've recently tried uisng Supabase with SvelteKit (Typescript) and it all went well unil all of a sudden, after few projects Typescript began compalining everytime I created a supabase.js file.

The error reads:
`Cannot write file 'c:/Users/x/x/src/lib/supabaseClient.js' because it would overwrite input file.`

I tried moving the file to different directories, but it still wouldn't work and like I said before, this error just to not occur when I would work on some other test projects before, and now every project I want to start, throws this error. Thank you for all the answers in advance!

Comment: There's insufficient information here. The TS error indicates that you're compiling a `.js` file with the TypeScript compiler without specifying an output location in your `tsconfig.json`. Since the typescript compiler outputs files with `.js` extensions,

Comment: It occurred to me in the shower, that it was that, after trying to debug it for the whole day haha. Thank you for the answer anyways!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the answer to this anomaly is that instead of naming the ending of the file with .js you have to name your files with .ts when working on a Typescript project, but of course,  me being a Typescript beginner I didn't think of that. Since I changed the file ending it now works. :))

Comment: I had the exact same issue and this fixed it, thanks for posting your solution!